# Trouble making ascii art in .bashrc file

Tags: bash, ascii-art

I get these errors when trying to use: export PS1='ascii text at bottom'.

bash: command substitution: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
bash: command substitution: line 1:`/  ^  \   |  |_)  |'
bash: command substitution: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
bash: command substitution: line 3:`   \    /\    / /  _____  \ |  |\  ---)   |'

Could someone explain why this doesn't work?

```
       ________________.  ___     .______  
      /                | /   \    |   _  \
     |   (-----|  |----`/  ^  \   |  |_)  |
      \   \    |  |    /  /_\  \  |      /
.------)   |   |  |   /  _____  \ |  |\  \-------.
|_________/    |__|  /__/     \__\| _| `.________|
____    __    ____  ___     .______    ________.
\   \  /  \  /   / /   \    |   _  \  /        |
 \   \/    \/   / /  ^  \   |  |_)  ||   (-----`
  \            / /  /_\  \  |      /  \   \
   \    /\    / /  _____  \ |  |\  \---)   |
    \__/  \__/ /__/     \__\|__| `._______/
```

Comment: Are you escaping all those characters correctly? `PS1` is an evaluated value.

Comment: Im just now learning how to use bash. Which characters do i escape and how?

Answer (score 3):

`PS1` is not just a plain string; in it, certain characters have meaning to them. You can find a surprisingly long document telling you more about bash prompts than you ever wanted to know [here](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/); it's a bit dated, but most of it should still hold. The particular problem you run into is that backslashes and backticks need to be escaped -- backslashes because they're used to escape things, and backticks because they're used for command substitutions -- and newlines are best replaced with the `\n` control sequence to avoid mishaps with lines that end in `\`. Ultimately, you want the effect of writing

```
export PS1='       ________________.  ___     .______  \n      /                | /   \\    |   _  \\\n     |   (-----|  |----\`/  ^  \\   |  |_)  |\n      \\   \\    |  |    /  /_\\  \\  |      /\n.------)   |   |  |   /  _____  \\ |  |\\  \\-------.\n|_________/    |__|  /__/     \\__\\| _| \`.________|\n____    __    ____  ___     .______    ________.\n\\   \\  /  \\  /   / /   \\    |   _  \\  /        |\n \\   \\/    \\/   / /  ^  \\   |  |_)  ||   (-----\`\n  \\            / /  /_\\  \\  |      /  \\   \\\n   \\    /\\    / /  _____  \\ |  |\\  \\---)   |\n    \\__/  \\__/ /__/     \\__\\|__| \`._______/'
```

...which is somewhat unwieldy. A way to do this on the fly so that it is easier on the eyes is

```
PS1='       ________________.  ___     .______  
      /                | /   \    |   _  \
     |   (-----|  |----`/  ^  \   |  |_)  |
      \   \    |  |    /  /_\  \  |      /
.------)   |   |  |   /  _____  \ |  |\  \-------.
|_________/    |__|  /__/     \__\| _| `.________|
____    __    ____  ___     .______    ________.
\   \  /  \  /   / /   \    |   _  \  /        |
 \   \/    \/   / /  ^  \   |  |_)  ||   (-----`
  \            / /  /_\  \  |      /  \   \
   \    /\    / /  _____  \ |  |\  \---)   |
    \__/  \__/ /__/     \__\|__| `._______/'

PS1="${PS1//\\/\\\\}"
PS1="${PS1//\`/\\\`}"
PS1="${PS1//
/\\n}"

export PS1    # <-- this isn't really necessary, by the way. PS1 is not
              #     usually used by processes the shell spawns.
```

Here `${variable//pattern/replacement}` is a bash-specific parameter expansion that expands to the value of `$variable` with all occurrences of `pattern` replaced with `replacement`. That is to say:

```
PS1="${PS1//\\/\\\\}"    # replaces \ with \\
PS1="${PS1//\`/\\\`}"    # replaces ` with \`
PS1="${PS1//             # replaces newlines with \n
/\\n}"
```

Comment: @rici You'd thinik so (I certainly did), but my version of bash (4.3.33) doesn't keep the newline after the lines that end in \ (in \\ after the replacement). I was surprised, but there we are.